# How can I feed standard input to a batch file when an app run from the batch mucks with stdin?

Tags: batch-file, stdin, dos

Here's a minimal batch file, `demo.bat`, to illustrate my problem:

```
@ECHO off

set /p foo=Enter foo:
echo.
echo you typed "%foo%"

sqlcmd -?

set /p bar=Enter bar:
echo.
echo you typed "%bar%"
```

I have an input file `foo.txt` that looks like so:

```
foo_value
bar_value
```

I run my batch file as `demo.bat < foo.txt`.  The output is:

```
Enter foo:
you typed "foo_value"
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Command Line Tool
Version 9.00.3042.00 NT INTEL X86
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: Sqlcmd            [-U login id]          [-P password]
  (...etc...)

Enter bar:
you typed "foo_value"
```

If I remove the `sqlcmd -?`, then bar is "typed" as `bar_value`, which is what I originally expected.

So, it looks to me like `sqlcmd` is not playing nice somehow with the standard input that wasn't meant for it.  Anyone have
any bright ideas on how I can work around it?  In a perfect world, the solution would not involve changing the original
batch file, or involve installing third-party packages to drive the interaction (e.g. Expect).

Comment: Are there any other commands or programs that exhibit this behavior? I don't have sqlcmd, and I can't find any other program that reproduces this problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also redirect NUL to sqlcmd:

```
sqlcmd -? < NUL
```

but this would require changing the batch script as well.

Comment: I don't expect there are any ways to do this without changing the original batch file, so we have a winner.  (I did try to create an `sqlcmd.bat` that runs sqlcmd.exe to try to trick it... but then I would need to add `CALL` to the original.  Oh well.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it helps, but you can try to pipe something else to sqlcmd, for example:

```
echo. | sqlcmd -?
```